# Limit of ratio of exponentials of different bases

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits-without-lhopital

As part of a larger problem I have a sequence whose limit I am not able to prove. The limit is

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\delta^{2^n-1}}{\gamma^n} \,,
$$

where both $0 < \delta < 1$ and $0 < \gamma < 1$ but we do not know the relationship between $\delta$ and $\gamma$ (which is larger).
Now numerical experiments indicate that this limit converges to zero even in the extreme case when $\delta$ is just under 1 and $\gamma$ is very small. Clearly this is due to the fact that $2^n-1$ increases much more quickly than $n$. I can't seem to prove this convergence though. Though this evaluates to the  indeterminate $0/0$, I shouldn't use L'Hopital. I don't think that helps you anyway since it doesn't get rid of the exponentials. Any ideas here? Am I missing something really simple?

Comment: Try taking the $\log.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe from the Binomial Theorem that $2^{n}-1=(1+1)^n-1\gt \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ if $n\ge 2$.

So, for $n\ge 2$, our expression is less than $\dfrac{\delta^{(n)(n-1)/2}}{\gamma^n}$.

This is equal to
$$\left(  \dfrac{\delta^{(n-1)/2}}{\gamma}\right)^n.$$
But $\dfrac{\delta^{(n-1)/2}}{\gamma}$ has limit $0$ as $n\to\infty$, and the result follows.

Comment: It looks like you switched around $\delta$ and $\gamma$. If so then I understand your argument perfectly, but if not then I think I'm still missing something.

Comment: I switched them by mistake, because to me $\gamma$ comes "before" $\delta$. Fixed. So I assume now everything is clear.  For big $n$, of course $2^n-1$ is hugely bigger than $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$, but the latter is convenient.

Comment: What do you mean the result follows? So what if the base has limit 0? It seems like before we get to the last line we can just use lhospitals on the expression in the penultimate line

Comment: The result follows because it's quite easy to prove that if $\lim_{n\to\infty} s_n = 0$ for a general real sequence $\{s_n\}$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty} (s_n)^n = 0$ also. EDIT: Also, I was trying to avoid using L'Hopital's rule as mentioned in the original post.

Comment: @BCLC: Presumably the bases $\delta$ and $\gamma$ are fixed. If we are allowed to make them functions of $n$, the limit is not necessarily $0$. The fact that if the positive sequence $b_n$ has limit $0$, so does $b_n^n$ is easily done by comparison. After a while $b_n\lt 1$, and then $b_n^n\le b_n$.

Comment: @kyp4 okay I proved it. Thanks